# F# strange agent re-initialisation behaviour

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

I have an F# 3.0 agent wrapped in a class:

```
type AgentWrapper() =
    let myAgent = Agent.Start(fun inbox ->
            let rec loop (state: int) =
                async {
                    let! (replyChannel: AsyncReplyChannel<int>) = inbox.Receive()
                    let newState = state + 1
                    replyChannel.Reply newState
                    return! loop newState
                }
            loop 0 )

    member private this.agent = myAgent

    member this.Send () = 
        this.agent.PostAndReply (fun replyChannel -> replyChannel)
```

When I send messages to it as follows:

```
let f = new AgentWrapper ()
f.Send () |> printf "Reply: %d\n"
f.Send () |> printf "Reply: %d\n"
f.Send () |> printf "Reply: %d\n"
```

I get the expected responses:

```
Reply: 1
Reply: 2
Reply: 3
```

However, if I remove the let binding for the agent and directly assign it to the this.agent property:

```
type AgentWrapper() =

    member private this.agent = Agent.Start(fun inbox ->
            let rec loop (state: int) =
                async {
                    let! (replyChannel: AsyncReplyChannel<int>) = inbox.Receive()
                    let newState = state + 1
                    replyChannel.Reply newState
                    return! loop newState
                }
            loop 0 )

    member this.Send () = 
        this.agent.PostAndReply (fun replyChannel -> replyChannel)
```

I then get the responses:

```
Reply: 1
Reply: 1
Reply: 1
```

I've been staring at this for hours and I can't understand why the agent is getting re-initialised every time I call AgentWrapper.Send. It feels like this.agent is getting reassigned every time I call it (i.e. acting like a method, not a property). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It feels like this.agent is getting reassigned every time I call it
>   (i.e. acting like a method, not a property). What am I missing?

This is exactly what happens, and is documented in the spec (relevant part from 18.13.1 follows)

> Static and instance property members are evaluated every time the
>   member is invoked. For example, in the following, the body of the
>   member is evaluated each time C.Time is evaluated:
>
> type C () =
>
> ```
> static member Time = System.DateTime.Now
> ```

This is analgous to your situation